# How to 'output' a alphabetically ordered list - Searchable Map Template with Google Fusion Tables by Derek Eder

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

hope somebody can help. I am playing around with 'Searchable Map Template with Google Fusion Tables by Derek Eder' also using result list. My question, is there any way to reorder the list, either alphabetically or by closest to the searched area?
Currently the order of the list stays in the order the rows were added on the fusion table. I have since changed the order on the fusion table to alphabetically, but the results table on my webpage stays in the order of when the rows were added.

New rows will be added all the time, so to be able to reorder the results list alphabetically or by distance to searched area is quite important to me.

Comment: I think somewhere within the maps_lib.js I will have to add       'ColumnName.sort();' but I am not quite sure where. I am guessing somewhere around for (var row in data)  {

Comment: What does your code look like?  What have you tried? Have you looked at adding 'ORDER BY' to your query? [order by distance example using GViz (not based on Derek's template)](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz_numbered.html) You refer to maps_lib.js but don't include your version or any information about what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is late, but for anyone wanting to do this, the following works

File: maps_lib.js

Date: 12/10/2012

Line: 210 - Add "Order by" - Note, I have chosen to use the **name** column, and sort A-Z

```
query: function(selectColumns, whereClause, callback) {
var queryStr = [];
queryStr.push("SELECT " + selectColumns);
queryStr.push(" FROM " + MapsLib.fusionTableId);
queryStr.push(" WHERE " + whereClause);
// Add sorting to table
queryStr.push(" ORDER BY name ASC");

var sql = encodeURIComponent(queryStr.join(" "));
$.ajax({url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql="+sql+"&callback="+callback+"&key="+MapsLib.googleApiKey, dataType: "jsonp"});
},
```

The bit I added was

```
queryStr.push(" ORDER BY name ASC");
```

Hope this helps if anyone else comes across this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this was something I had to drop for the time being, but I have just implemented your change and it works perfect :) Is it possible to order by nearest location?

Comment: Not sure if you have solved this or not, but the answer is yes.  Add this to the end of your SELECT statement:   `ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(<column name where location data is held>, <point from which distance is measured>)`